# NetBeans fails to format one particular source file

Tags: java, netbeans, code-formatting, netbeans-8

NetBeans 8.1 successfully applies my code formatting rules when I choose Source > Format and when I save a file (an option I enabled). Except for one particular .java source file.

The project compiles successfully. The file is 8K long. A gig of free memory still available in the operating system (Mac OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion). Java version 1.8.0_65-b17.

Why would code formatting fail for just one particular file?

Comment: Can you format the file in chunks by highlighting multiple methods at once? I'm curious if maybe the formatter is getting hung up on something it finds difficult to understand and this might help you find what that is.

Comment: No, selecting several lines and choosing *Source* > *Format* has no effect.

Comment: I resolved this problem by copying entire method contents into a text editor, deleting contents in NetBeans editor, then copy-pasting one method at a time back into NetBeans. Worked, solved the problem, NetBeans now formats the file. Perhaps there was some non-appearing gremlin character in there somewhere, but I did not find it.